# How to mix CSS inset shadows in a 50:50 proportion?

Tags: css

I would like to mix two inset box shadows. It should look like that, with a tiny smooth transition between:

[image]

I have tried to code it this way:

```css
#button_one,
#button_two,
#button_three {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

#button_one {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px gray, inset 0 5px 5px red;
}

#button_two {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px gray, inset 0 5px 5px blue;
}

#button_three {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px gray, inset 0 5px 5px red, inset 0 5px 5px blue; /* What would be a solution here? */
}
```

```html
<div id="button_one">Red Shadow Button</div> <!-- Looks good -->
<div id="button_two">Blue Shadow Button</div> <!-- Looks good -->
<div id="button_three">Red Blue Shadow Button</div> <!-- Looks bad! -->
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work the way like in the image. Additionally, there should be a normal gray box shadow like in the code example. Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two pseudo element, one for each shadow then a mask to create the small fading effect in the middle

```css
div[id] {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

div[id]:before,
div[id]:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: inherit;
  inset: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 5px 5px var(--c, red);
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(var(--p, 90deg), #0000 45%, #000 55%);
  pointer-events: none;
}

div[id]:after {
  --c: blue;
  --p: -90deg;
}
```

```html
<div id="button_one">Red Shadow Button</div>
<div id="button_two">Blue Shadow Button</div>
<div id="button_three">Red Blue Shadow Button</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you! It looks amazing! I just realized that I also need additionally a normal box shadow with a gray color. I updated my code for that. And I tried to add it to your code, but it doesn't get shown unfortunately → https://jsfiddle.net/6r4q9om1/ – Could you look at that please?

Comment: @Anna_B add that shadow to the main element not the pseudo element

Comment: let me ask a question why the black after 55% can not override red or blue? @TemaniAfif

Comment: @UPinar it's a mask not a background

Comment: okay than #0000 is not letting any color get out from mask